# What is the $Ass(Ext^p_R(M,R))$?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, modules

Let $R$ be a Noetherian commutative local ring, $M$ a finitely generated $R$-module with $p=pd M<\infty$ (projective dimension of $M$). What is the relation between $Ass(Ext^p_R(M,R))$ and $Ass(M)$?
Thanks.

Comment: Could you please clarify your question.  What do you want to know about the set of associated primes.  These primes are contained in the support of $M$.  Are you asking about (upper) bounds on the heights of these primes?

Comment: I want to know the relation of $Ass(Ext^p_R(M,R))$ with $Ass M.$

Comment: Unfortunately, that does not clarify the question.  Certainly all associated primes of $\text{Ext}^p_R(M,R)$ contain the annihilator ideal of $M$.  Thus, each contains one of the minimal associated primes of $M$.  Beyond that, what is your expectation?  Consider, for instance, the special case that $R$ equals $k[x_0,\dots,x_n]$ and $M$ equals the maximal ideal $\langle x_0,\dots,x_n \rangle$.  Then $p$ equals $n>0$, and $\text{Ext}^n_R(M,R)$ equals $R/M=k.$  The unique associated prime of $R/M$ equals $M$.  The unique associated prime of $M$ equals $\{0\}$.  Direct sums give more examples.

Comment: Do we have $Ass(M)\subseteq Ass(Ext^p_R(M,R))$ ?

Comment: No, you do not have that.  Again, consider the example that $M$ is the maximal ideal $\langle x_0,\dots,x_n \rangle$ in the polynomial ring $k[x_0,\dots,x_n]$ for $n>0$.  Then $\text{Ass}(M)$ equals the singleton set consisting only of the zero ideal $\{0\}$.  Yet $\text{Ass}(\text{Ext}^n_R(M,R))$ equals the singleton set consisting only of the ideal $M$.

Comment: Thanks you very much. @Jason Starr

Comment: You are welcome.